# How to display references entities in single field?

Tags: 7, views, entities, users

I have a view of nodes. These nodes are connected with users via entity reference. User has a profile (Profile2). I want to display profile fields for all referenced users in single field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use something like [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) and pass your node number as an argument, then use the reverse relationship to list members.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that there is a way for avoiding additional module (besides custom coding) but it's probably the only way. Do you know how to display all rows inline (without overriding view templates)?

Comment: No I don't, sorry, I think that's exactly what templates are for.

Comment: Actually it works out of the box, I've just added entity reference field to a view and setted formatter: entityreference_username_profile

Comment: Sweet, that's good to know =)